# jqPlot yaxis ticks not correlating to series values when using multi series

Tags: jqplot

I have an issue with jqPlot not plotting the correct yaxis. I have a y-axis of monetry values 0 - ~3500

I then have an x-axis of dates, eg jan 12, feb 12 etc going forward in time.

I then have 4 series of data - min, avg, max and total.

total has a maximum value of 3222 however this is displayed along side a y-axis of 4500;

my graph options are as follows:

```
graphOptions = 
{
    seriesColors: [ "#4bb2c5", "#c5b47f", "#EAA228", "#579575", "#839557", "#958c12",
        "#953579", "#4b5de4", "#d8b83f", "#ff5800", "#0085cc"],
    stackSeries: true,
    title: 'Redemption Rates BAND: 0-50',
    legend: {
        show: true,
        placement: 'outsideGrid'
    },
    highlighter: {
        show: true,
        sizeAdjust: 7.5,
        useAxesFormatters: true,
        formatString : '%s, &pound;%s',
        tooltipLocation: 'ne'
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer:  $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
            tickOptions:{formatString:'%#d %b<br />%Y'},
            tickInterval: '1 month' 
        },
        yaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,
            tickOptions: {formatter: function(format, val){
                return numeral(val).format('£0,0.00');
            }}
        }
    },
    cursor:{ 
        show: true,
        zoom:true, 
        showTooltip:false
    } 
};
```

I have created a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/NLZ3A/ (excuse code)

I think its adding the values of each series together to get rough y-axis values bu these then do not correlate to the actual line values - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set

```
stackSeries: false
```

inside your `graphOptions` object. this would solve your problem